# Rails global Time.zone.now object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

During a request I use a variable `now = Time.zone.now` several times, and I would like them to be the same object. I could use a helper method to create a cached value but this `now` variable will also be used in the models. Is there a `Rails.now` object or something I can use? If not, where would be the cleanest place to define such a global timestamp?

Comment: Why don't you use directly Time.zone.now (without storing it in a local variable) ?

Comment: Because every time this is called it returns a new object with a slightly different time stamp, as far as I understand.

Comment: maybe you can use `Date.today` instead of `Time.zone.now`?

Comment: Can you pass the cached timestamp as an argument to the models? Because using a global for a value that can change over time smells like trouble, IMHO.